# Using reflection inside enums but always getting NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, reflection, enums, talend

I'm building a custom component for Talend Open Studio to access a source of data from an application (JIRA) that has a wrapper to get all its data. It exposes an API full of very volatile getters for all its data structure. Since Talend Open Studio supports primitive type only, i usually need to chain several call to get a primitive data (ie. Project.getProjectDetail().getOwner().getName())

But these API often vary and i don't want to change my code every time. So i decided to use an enumeration of methods: when a new field is exposed, i need only to add an element to the enumeration. Something like that:

(i cut most elements to be concise)

```
public enum JiraProjectField {

    KEY(new String[]{"getKey"}),
    COMPONENTS_NUM(new String[]{"getComponents", "size"}),

    private Method[] m;
    private ArrayList<Class<?>> r;

    private JiraProjectField(String[] methods) {

        this.r = new ArrayList<Class<?>>(methods.length);

        Class<?> initClass = Project.class;
        for(int i=0; i< methods.length; i++){
            try {
                m[i] = initClass.getMethod(methods[0], (Class<?>)null);
                r.add(m[i].getReturnType());
                initClass = m[i].getReturnType();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e.toString());
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e.toString());
            }
        }
}
```

But I always get a NoSuchMethodException, even if i'm *sure* the method with that name exists. Is there something i don't know?

Comment: It's not clear what enums have to do this. Are you saying this code works *outside* an enum? It would really help if you'd give a short but *complete* example of this failing.

Comment: What is the signature of the method?

Comment: Sure it's a public method in a public class?

Comment: *"Is there something i don't know?"* Thomas Edison was heard to say "We don't know a millionth of 1% about anything.".  So I expect the answer to that is.  Yes.

Comment: I don't know even an estimate of how much I don't. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey  I always thought Edison was being optimistic in pegging it at that upper limit.  I'd have estimated a lower knowledge ratio.

Comment: don't blame my english, you all know what i meant :P

Comment: @TheClue We know because we are not so different ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why you are not using varargs more but you can try

```
m[i] = initClass.getMethod(methods[i]);
```

Comment: Ah yes, it `getMethod(methods[0], new Class<?>[] { null });` which actually looks like unspecified behaviour.

Comment: +1, it was much more easier than i supposed. The problem was with that cast Class<?>; remove the cast resolved the issue. However I'm wondering if i could find a better design (an array of method instead of an array of string? a varargs prototype? nothing like that?)

Comment: You will be able to in Java 8 as it has first class method objects. i.e. you can refer to a method and access it without explicit use of reflection.